# Validating an XML file without an xsd file

Tags: c#, xml

I found a lot of great questions on this subject.  Unfortunately the answers all say to use an xsd file.  I made an xsd file from an xml file using xsd.exe.  I copied code from [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/xml/article.php/c6737/Validation-of-XML-with-XSD.htm) and pasted into Visual studio and I got an error on the first line.

Not wanted to spend time figuring out why it would not run I decided to code the validation myself.

Here are the two points I am using:

1. Each left caret will have a right caret, so at the end of the file their will be an equal amount of left and right carets.
2. At the end of the file, if I either take the amount of left carets, or the amount of right carets subtract one from the total (Because the header does not have a backslash) and divide the total by two, I get the number of slashes.

I am encountering some problems though.

1. I am using string.count()  This method also counts carets that are in the attributes (Which I do not want).
2. I compute the expected number of backslashes when I am done reading the file.  If the numbers do not match I write "The expected number of slashes do not match" But I don't know where it is in the file.

I can't think of a way to fix these problems at the moment.

Does anyone have a better way to validate an xml file without using an xsd file?

Comment: What does validate mean in this context? If you want to ensure it is a valid XML file of any kind, `XDocument.Load` does the trick. If you want to ensure that it matches a particular set of constraints something like XSD is ideal. It sounds to me like you found a sample of XSD, had difficulty compiling it, and jumped straight to manual parsing. There are better ways of doing it (if you are counting total `<`/`>` you are going to get it wrong) but a major factor is how many requirements you have of the input file.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Figure out what's wrong with your xsd, that'll be simpler in the long run. Trust me.

Comment: You're not validating XML. You're just counting pairs of `<>`, which is not the same thing at all. XSD validates data types, and can ensure that required elements are included. Your validation does less than simply loading the XML into a basic XML parser. You should fix your XSD instead of wasting your time and effort, IMO.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take note that WELL FORMED XML is different to VALID XML.

XML that adheres to the XML standard is considered well formed, while XML that adheres to a DTD is considered VALID.

If you just want to check if XML is well formed try this:

```
try
{
    var file = "Your xml path";

    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore, XmlResolver = null };

    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(file), settings))
    {
        var document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(reader);
    }
}

catch (Exception exc)
{
    //show the exception here
}
```

P.S: Well formedness of an XML is always a prerequisite of a valid XML.

Hope it helps!

Comment: +1, but wondering why you don't just suggest XmlDocument.Load(filename)?

Comment: Thank you very much.  This works and is a lot better than the mess I was trying to come up with.

Comment: Agree with @JasonWilliams. Passing the filename / path directly to .Load also allows URLs to be passed.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "caret", I think you must be talking about the "<" and ">" symbols, which in the XML world are usually referred to as "angle brackets".

When you talk about checking whether the carets match up, you are therefore talking about whether the file conforms to XML syntax. That's called "well-formedness checking" in the XML world. Validation is something different and deeper. You need a schema (either an XSD schema or some other kind) for validation, but for well-formedness checking all you need is an XML parser.

Don't try to implement the well-formedness checking yourself. (a) because it's not easy, (b) because parsers are readily available off-the-shelf, and (c) because you clearly don't have a very advanced understanding of the problem. Just run your file through an XML parser and it will do the job for you.

Comment: What XML Parser should I use?

Comment: That's a bit like asking what car you should drive. If all you want to do is check the data for well-formedness, use the nearest one available, unless you have very specialized requirements.